# On click of edit Date is not populating

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

> Below code contains start date and end date, when i save the date in
>   mongodb it is in ISODate( ISODate("2013-02-01T18:30:00.000+0000") )
>   format but when i try to edit the date will not appear in the input but when i 
>   try to display ng.model it will contain date in the format
>   2012-02-01T18:30:00.000Z
>   box what is the reason??

```
<div class="form-group" show-errors>
             <label class="control-label" for="sdate">Start Date</label>
             <input  name="sdate" type="date" ng-model="vm.batch.sdate" id="sdate" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Start Date" required>
             {{vm.batch.sdate}}

             <div ng-messages="vm.form.batchForm.sdate.$error" role="alert">
               <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Start Date is required.</p>
             </div>
           </div>

            <div class="form-group" show-errors>
             <label class="control-label" for="edate">End Date</label>
             <input name="edate" type="date" ng-model="vm.batch.edate" id="edate" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="End Date" required>
             {{vm.batch.edate}}
             <div ng-messages="vm.form.batchForm.edate.$error" role="alert">
               <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">End Date is required.</p>
             </div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass dateobject in ng-model instead of a simple date string

In your controller you may do something like

```
$scope.vm.batch.sdate=new Date(your date string here);
```

[Here is working example](http://jsfiddle.net/b107temk/)

Answer (score 0):

The Reason is the input type date required date object and your ng-model contain ISO date string values that's why it's not show date in input box.

please convert ISO Date string to date object

```
vm.batch.sdate = new Date(vm.batch.sdate);
vm.batch.edate = new Date(vm.batch.edate);
```

Comment: it is working but it is skipping one day i.e if my date is 22-2-2017  if i click edit it will show 23-2-2017

Comment: try this to convert ISO to date                                                                    date = new Date('2013-03-10T02:00:00Z');
date.getFullYear()+'-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-'+date.getDate()